# Is it Okay to use on click in view model?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I am using navigation component and I want to traverse from one fragment to another so is it okay if I used it like below

```
fun customClick(view: View) {
        view.apply {
            when (id) {
                R.id.icon -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_name)      
            }
        }
    }
```

and I use this method with databinding in my activity like below

```
android:onClick="@{(view)->viewmodel.customClick(view)}"
```

I know view model is designed to store and manage UI-related data. So Is it good practice to work like above code?

Comment: Better keep navigation stuff inside Ui element i.e fragment/Activity because it depends on `Context`  . because you are not gonna find `findNavController()`  inside `ViewModel` anyway  . `findNavController()` is an extension on fragment

Comment: currently I am using ```view.findNavController()``` for navigate and its working properly. But my question is that is it acceptable or not?

Comment: Its not only about `findNavController` what if you have to access some other stuff on click of   fragment for exa databinding Object  . As i said keep it in UI  element .